# pymodbus read meter registers

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I'm new to modbus but I have a small project to work on. I need to read some values from an energy meter. I wrote this from some examples found in the internet:

```
import logging
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = ModbusClient('192.168.80.210')
client.connect() 
rr = client.read_holding_registers(40012, 1)
print rr

client.close()
```

It seems to be connecting to the meter 'cause this is my output:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x6 0x0 0x3 0x9c 0x4c 0x0 0x1
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Transaction failed. (Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 8 bytes (0 received)) 
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.socket_framer:Processing: 
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 8 bytes (0 received)
```

I want to read from register `40012` to `40014` and this is Modbusdbus map I have:
[Modbus map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2nCR.png)

I appreciate your help. Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set the `unit` and `port` argument, and for getting the value use the `rr.registers`, so you need to know the unit_ID value, and the device port.

In most cases, the `unit` is `1` and the `port` is `502` as the modbus default.

If you want to read from address `40012` to `40014`, you could read from `40012` as a bulky reading with `count=3`.

---

I improved your code, try it:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.80.210', port=502)

if client.connect():
    res = client.read_holding_registers(40012, count=3, unit=1)

    if not res.isError():
    '''.isError() was implemented in pymodbus version 1.4.0 and above.'''
        print(res.registers)
    else:
        # handling error
        print(res)

client.close()
```

Comment: Thank! you are right. I was missing unit, in this case the unit is 100, now I have registers returning from the device.

Comment: @LuisJavierAlvarezRodriguez good luck, with upvote we could improve the Stack Overflow question/answer,  and the minimum reputation for upvotes is 15.