# Pymodbus Register Custom Format with Serial Client

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I have a **Serial Client**, which uses a custom format on top of the Modbus protocol, so I have to decode the answers accordingly. However, I don't seem to be able to register my function with the Serial Client, as I get an Error:

```
AttributeError: 'ModbusSerialClient' object has no attribute 'register'
```

Looking into the source code reveals that the `.register()` function is only implemented for TcpClient. Is this by design? And if so, how do I deal with the custom format for a SerialClient?

Comment: What about the plural; `registers`?

Comment: The function is called `.register()`

Comment: Both `tcp` and `serial` clients do not have an attribute `register` . I believe you are confusing with the register response which has a `registers` attribute. For e.g refer https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/examples/common/synchronous_client.py#L137

Comment: Keep in mind Modbus cliend request hasn't `.register` so it should be `.registers` and check `.isError()` before trying to achive `.registers`. [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53421006/3702377).

Comment: Alright, thanks for answering. I worded this question really badly so I think I'll just delete this one and ask a new one. It was actually concerning an example of a CustomModbus message [here](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/custom_message.html), where the `.register()` function was used to register the custom response class presumably with the function tables in `factory.py`. I couldn't get this to work with `ModbusSerialClient`, hence the question. I wanted to use this because I didn't want to edit the libraries but insert my custom classes at runtime if possible.